# Query slow when executing with actual execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-execution-plan

I'm trying to optimize a stored procedure. When ran in management studio, it takes about 40 seconds. When ran with the "Include actual execution plan" toggled on, it takes over 10 minutes, sometimes longer. During those 10 minutes, SMSS.exe hogs a whole CPU core, so possibly a client issue.

The stored procedure is fairly big, over 2k rows, so the query plan is also quite large. This happens only for the SP, on multiple machines. It doesn't happen every time, it seems to come and go. Sometimes, when the cancel button is clicked during the execution, management studio comes up with a semi-random nondescript error message.

SMSS 10.50.1600.1 , SQL 2008 R2

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it one big query or multiple statements inside the SP?

Comment: @Magnus the latter. It's about 20-25 statements in total.

Comment: Try taking them out form the SP and analyse them one by one in management studio

Comment: Did you try generating an actual plan from [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer)? Probably won't be any different but might be worth a shot. Tough to know the problem unless you investigate what your session is actually waiting on for those 10 minutes (Plan Explorer PRO will tell you that directly with less digging). *Disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry.*

Comment: In my experience, some times erratic behaviour like this by SQL Server can be helped be re-indexing the database(s) involved.